# C#.net Error at BeginTransaction (?) (MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters, transactions

The error I'm getting is pointing to when I call

> cmd.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso);

[error description click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGWV8.png)

This method is called the the user tries to sign up on log in webpage. If HTML5 client-side input verification is accepted and both password fields match, this method is called and empty textboxes are filled with a space (" ").

This is for my senior project, please help.

```
     //this method adds a record to the table customers
    public Boolean addUser(String email, String password, String name, String phone, String company, String address, String city, String state, String zip)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        MySqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
        cmd.Connection = conn;            
        cmd.Transaction = trans;
        try {
            conn.Open();  
            //these are the mandatory fields to be inserted)
        string sql = "Insert into customers(name,password,phone,email) values (?name,?password,?phone,?email)";
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name",  name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email", email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?phone",  phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?password", password);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
            conn.Close();
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            //these fields are optional and if input is empty they are being passed as " "
            sql = "Update customers Set username = ?company, address=?address ,city=?city, state=?state, zipcode=?zip  where customerID=MAX(customerID)";
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?company",  company);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?address",  address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?city", city);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?state", state);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?zip",  zip);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            errorcode = ex.Number;
            MessageBox.Show("7. Sign Up  Failure\nError code: " + getError(), "Sign Up failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
            conn.Close();
            return false;
        }           
        
        return true;
    }
```

Update:
IF I don't include the transaction methods, the error i'll get is when I perform the second database transaction (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())

[See error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdr1p.png)

It would be nice to implement the IsolationLEvel Serializable since it stops other Database transactions from occurring at the same time. But at this point I'm just trying to get users to sign up.

Comment: What is the message of exception?

Comment: You say the error is caused by `cmd.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso);` but your included code doesn't have that in it. Can you also include the code that has that line in it?

Comment: MySqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);

Comment: the message of exception is the clickable text. IF you click on it you will see the image with the box containing the error

Comment: That's the message box and error message displayed by your code. What is the value of `ex.Message`? What is the code of `getError` method?

Comment: Why are you running an INSERT then an UPDATE? The INSERT should be sufficient...